# Pass the return from MYSQL into a function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to pass data returned from a query into the function below.  I have put the returned data into the variable $startvalue.  I need to pass that variable into the function at the part "initialValue:" but no matter how I try the value is not passed. I have tried putting the variable directly in between the ticks.  Add " to either end and fiddled with every conceivable combination I have used in the past but still nothing.  I even tried passing the variable to another like this: var initval=$startvalue; and tried to pass that into the function but still nothing.  I know the function works because if I enter a numeral manually it does what its supposed to do.  Im stumped.

```
$(function() {

$("#rating").rateme({
    Length: '5',
    initialValue: '',
    callbackFunctionName: 'processRating',
    imageDirectory: 'images/',
    inputAttr: 'postID'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to begin the PHP parser.

`initialValue: '<?php echo $startvalue; ?>',`

or

`initialValue: '<?= $startvalue ?>',`

To avoid escaping/quote issues, a good trick is to use json_encode when inserting data into Javascript variables:

`initialValue: <?= json_encode($startvalue) ?>,`

Comment: Doh!! It didnt even occur to me to do that.  As my dad always says.  Hast makes waste.  I should have stopped trying to riddle it and taken a step back and looked at the whole thing.  Lesson learned.  Thanks @rjdown